# why does php add pre- and postfix to body?

Tags: php, apache, api, request

I try to get a php api working, but i monitored requests and php ads a pre- and postfix. no idea why. But its not getting showed in my browser (2c and 0). strange.

here the request:

```
GET /tasks?dk=123 HTTP/1.1
Host: device.mydomain.eu
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 10 Jun 2014 10:20:20 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.9
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json

2c
{"tasks":[{"feature":"start","action":"1"}]}
0
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It's not added by PHP, it is added by Apache. This is due to the chunked transfer. You are receiving one chunk, the first one being 44 characters long (or 2c in hexadecimal notation).

Chunked responses always end with a chunk containing 0 bytes, to indicate the end.